# Organizing our Linguistics Blog

Tags: discussion

SE sites do not have a blog by default but we can request one. I ask you to read [this blog entry](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/), which is related to this topic.

Keeping in mind that we should post there at least once a week (not necessarily the same person), we could catch the interest of some important linguist and this would *greatly* help our site. Imagine a linguist writing in our blog. And imagine the effects of this.

The [four steps](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/) which are necessary to get a full functioning blog are:

1. <s>*Post a topic on Meta*</s>: done.
2. [*Define content and scope*](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/419/111)
3. [*Recruit contributors*](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/411/111): Add your name to the list if you would like to participate. The more people the better, so we could take turns.
4. *Plan a schedule*

Write down the topics you would like to talk about or the ones you'd like to see treated. You case you have lots of ideas, you could consider committing yourself to the cause! :)

Comment: Are you saying that the linguists who already participate here *aren't* important?? ;-)

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut Ahah actually I don't know if there is someone "known" here... Is there? :D

Comment: @Alenanno, I know for sure that there are some notable linguists here, some of them use their real names, some prefer to disguise themselves. The thing is that some of them already have their own blogs, and this new blog would be a serious commitment, timewise.

Comment: @AlexB. No-one denies them from sharing their own articles here too. :D I mean, a professional linguist, shares in his own blog and then also here... Why not? I wouldn't care. No-one would.

Comment: I would participate but I couldn't be the actual blogger.

Comment: @hippietrail What do you mean?

Comment: @Alenanno: Most of the SE blogs (I believe but I might be wrong) have one person who is responsible for putting together each edition of the blog, encourage people to contribute articles, etc.

Comment: @hippietrail Do we need that? I mean, I think we're all adults here. If you (general) sign up, I assume you're going to write.

Comment: I'm not sure if we need it or not. On travel.SE we asked if somebody wanted to do it: **[Who wants to be the Travel Stack Exchange blogger?](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/433/who-wants-to-be-the-travel-stack-exchange-blogger)** -- of course over there somebody did step up for the job but didn't in fact start the blog yet ...

Comment: Also, I assume there must be certain site features for publishing the blog that are only available to diamonds or to the appointed blogger or something like that.

Comment: @hippietrail I think that the publishing privilege of articles, if it exists, will be given to those who step up. I'm not asking to write tons of stuff. If we get 8 people, each one of us is going to post once a month, one month yes, one month not. :) Not so bad, no?

Comment: I would love linguistics-specific blogging! I've recently started my own blog, but it doesn't really fit with the type of linguistics stuff I want to all about. A linguistics-specific blog, on the other hand, if a different story. I would certainly participate.

Comment: Do we really need *eight* people? I think a more important thing to think about is do we have enough topics to keep going for awhile. You can have 100 people willing to blog, but if none of them have any idea what they want to talk about, we're back to square one. I would say we just need enough people with enough ideas that the blog can have at least 2 posts a month for at least a year. On my personal blog, as soon as I launched, I wrote a bunch of evergreen posts that I can quickly publish if I run out of ideas for awhile. That sort of thing could work here as well.

Comment: @NickAnderegg The 8 people limit is there for two reasons. First, because if we are 2 (an example) and the other one disappears, the one remaining is alone. Second because this way, we can divide the work. I can't write a blog post too often, and I suppose the others have stuff to do too, so I'm looking for a compromise. In any case, if we keep being 4 for enough time, we'll start anyway! :)

Comment: Makes sense. It would still make sense for those who are able to to write some evergreen content beforehand as well, just in case something happens where nobody is able to update. Then it can *look* like we're still being productive! :)

Comment: @NickAnderegg Any suggestion is welcome! :) If you have multiple suggestions, you could add an answer. A comment is too narrow for that. :)

Comment: I don't have a whole ton of specific ideas, but a lot of ideas for what I could write consist of prescriptive vs. descriptive linguistics. Like how it's impossible to say "I feel nauseated" without sounding pretentious and you should just say "nauseous." Or how the idea of using "substitute words" rather than curse words is absurd, since you are conveying the *exact* same meaning, just with a different morpheme.

Comment: Oh! Book reviews! That could be a good go-to. I'm currently writing a review for "Our Magnificent Bastard Tongue" on my own blog, and that sort of things would certainly draw more visitors if it were on a blog here.

Comment: @NickAnderegg That sounds good... Do you mind to use it as our first article when we start?

Comment: That could work. I just posted it here: http://labbook.net/2012/08/16/linguistics-book-review-our-magnificent-bastard-tongue/ Not sure if this is the writing style we would want to aim for, but it's a start.

Comment: Why not just have a meta topic somewhere that everybody can edit to add ideas for blog topics as they see them in the news or in our questions, or just think them up?

Comment: [Here it is](http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/419/111) :P

Answer (score 3):

People who are willing to write an article now and then (regularly but with turns):

- Alenanno
- Alex B.
- Gaston Ü.
- Nick Anderegg
- ...

Answer (score 1):

### Brainstorming Blog topics (work in progress)

> **Note**: The blog is going to treat about Linguistics itself and the site as well.

- How to answer a question (in general and specifically about Linguistics SE)
- Linguistics terminology
- Book reviews
- News (some fascinating/groundbreaking/revolutionary paper was published, etc.)
- Generally interesting linguistics topics that have come up in recent questions

  - The proposed [Dené-Yeniseian family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Den%C3%A9%E2%80%93Yeniseian_languages)
- Endangered language of the month?

Comment: + Pointers to other blogs

Comment: @kaleissin What do you mean?

Comment: There are tons of linguistics blogs out there, it's always fun to discover another. There could be a little show-and-tell: "this blog which was started in x concentrates on the language of food and food terms", "this is the official blog of famed linguist so-and-so", "Conference y lives on in the blog z", etc. etc. but with a lot more detail of course. More to the point: There are blogs that refuse to talk about other blogs in the same genre, such blogs don't survive for long in my feedreader. It's also nice with some safe fillers when there are nothing better to write about.

Comment: @kaleissin I am afraid that is not included in the "scope". I mean, we are either talking about Linguistics or one of its subdisciplines, or this site. Besides, I don't see how redirecting to other blogs would help our site. This blog thing is aimed to increase participation here, bringing people to visit our site. If I suggest other blogs...